# unable to resize image in php?

Tags: php, image-processing

I am currently having problem re-sizing images in upload form of php.
**Here is my code :**

```
<?php
// Function for resizing jpg, gif, or png image files
function ak_img_resize($target, $newcopy, $w, $h, $ext) {
    list($w_orig, $h_orig) = getimagesize($target);
    $scale_ratio = $w_orig / $h_orig;
    if (($w / $h) > $scale_ratio) {
           $w = $h * $scale_ratio;
    } else {
           $h = $w / $scale_ratio;
    }
    $img = "";
    $ext = strtolower($ext);
    if ($ext == "gif"){ 
      $img = imagecreatefromgif($target);
    } else if($ext =="png"){ 
      $img = imagecreatefrompng($target);
    } else { 
      $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($target);
    }
    $tci = imagecreatetruecolor($w, $h);
    // imagecopyresampled(dst_img, src_img, dst_x, dst_y, src_x, src_y, dst_w, dst_h, src_w, src_h)
    imagecopyresampled($tci, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $w, $h, $w_orig, $h_orig);
    imagejpeg($tci, $newcopy, 80);
}
?>
<?php
  if (isset($_FILES['profilepic'])) {
   if (((@$_FILES["profilepic"]["type"]=="image/jpeg") || (@$_FILES["profilepic"]["type"]=="image/png") || (@$_FILES["profilepic"]["type"]=="image/gif"))&&(@$_FILES["profilepic"]["size"] < 1048576)) //1 Megabyte
  {
   $chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
   $rand_dir_name = substr(str_shuffle($chars), 0, 15);
   $dir = "/home/rahulkapoor90/public_html/userdata/profile_pics/$rand_dir_name";
   mkdir($dir);
    move_uploaded_file(@$_FILES["profilepic"]["tmp_name"],"/home/rahulkapoor90/public_html/userdata/profile_pics/$rand_dir_name/".$_FILES["profilepic"]["name"]);
    $profile_pic_name = @$_FILES["profilepic"]["name"];
$target_file = "http://www.hootpile.com/userdata/profile_pics/$rand_dir_name/$profile_pic_name";
$resized_file = "http://www.hootpile.com/userdata/profile_pics/$rand_dir_name/resized_$profile_pic_name";
$wmax = 200;
$hmax = 150;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
ak_img_resize($target_file, $resized_file, $wmax, $hmax, $imageFileType);
    $profile_pic_query = mysqli_query($conn,"UPDATE users2 SET profile_pic='$rand_dir_name/$profile_pic_name' WHERE username='$user'");

  }
  else
  {
      echo  "Invailid File! Your image must be no larger than 1MB and it must be either a .jpg, .jpeg, .png or .gif";
  }
  }

?>
```

I am able to upload my image to the database but the resize function doesn't seem to work and is unable to reduce the image size.

Comment: Please add some comments to your code, and are you sure you are saving the correct (resized)image not the original one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing an url to imagejpeg function. The output file have to be the path to local directory as follows

```
$resized_file =  "/home/rahulkapoor90/public_html/userdata/profile_pics/$rand_dir_name/resized_$profile_pic_name"
```

And apache must be allowed to write to the $resized_file